# how to do one hot encoding for text in a paragraph at the sentence level?

Tags: python, nlp, one-hot-encoding

I have sentences stored in text file which looks like this.

```
radiologicalreport =1.  MDCT OF THE CHEST   History: A 58-year-old male, known case lung s/p LUL segmentectomy.  Technique: Plain and enhanced-MPR CT chest is performed using 2 mm interval.  Previous study: 03/03/2018 (other hospital)  Findings:   Lung parenchyma: The study reveals evidence of apicoposterior segmentectomy of LUL showing soft tissue thickening adjacent surgical bed at LUL, possibly post operation.
```

My ultimate goal is to apply LDA to classify each sentence to one topic. Before that, I want to do one hot encoding to the text. The problem I am facing is I want to one hot encode per sentence in a numpy array to be able to feed it into LDA. If I want to one hot encode the full text, I can easily do it using these two lines.

```
sent_text = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
hot_encode=pd.Series(sent_text).str.get_dummies(' ')
```

However, my goal is to one hot encoding per sentence in a numpy array. So, I try the following code.

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import nltk
import pandas as pd


from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize

with open('radiologicalreport.txt', 'r') as myfile:
report=myfile.read().replace('\n', '') 
tokenizer_words = TweetTokenizer()
tokens_sentences = [tokenizer_words.tokenize(t) for t in 
nltk.sent_tokenize(report)]
tokens_np = array(tokens_sentences)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(tokens_np)

# binary encode
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)

onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
```

I get an error at this line as "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

```
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(tokens_np)
```

And hence cannot proceed further. 
Also, my tokens_sentences look like this as shown in the [image]image.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to transform labels to numerical values using `fit_transform` (in your example labels are lists of words -- `tokens_sentences`).

But non-numerical labels can be transformed only if they are *hashable and comparable* (see [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#label-encoding)). Lists are not hashable but you can convert them to tuples:

```
tokens_np = array([tuple(s) for s in tokens_sentences]) 
# also ok: tokens_np = [tuple(s) for s in tokens_sentences]
```

and then you can get your sentences encoded in `integer_encoded`

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(tokens_np)
```